# Present Pefect Continous + Simple Past

Tags: tenses

Is it okay to say:

I have been feeling bad because I had an argument 2 days ago?

Or is it better to say:

I feel bad because I had an argument 2 days ago?

---

I would like to emphasise that I still feel bad, I thought about the first option with Present Perfect Continous. It could be better but I want to be sure.

Comment: When you change the tense, you change the meaning. Both these sentences are grammatical, but they mean different things. It's not a question of one being "better" than the other. One is probably better at saying what you want to express, but you have given no information about that. How long have you been feeling bad? Do you still feel bad?

Answer (score 0):

Well both are correct. For the one, it is possible that the person has been feeling bad since the argument, and for the other, it is possible that the person, after two days, is starting to feel bad about the argument.